# CiviDiscount compatibility with CiviCRM 5.9

Tags: cividiscount

Is CiviDiscount compatible with CiviCRM 5.9?
We can't make it work with a 5.9 install on Joomla 3.9.1.
Thank you

**Edit:**
The issue is when trying to access the CiviDiscount GUI (e.g. Administer >> CiviDiscount), the user is taken to CiviCRM dashboard/home instead of the CiviDiscount UI.

I'm using a user in the Super Admin user group so it's not permissions related.

Discounts in the front end (both autodiscounts and entering a discount code), e.g. in event registration, work fine, but we can't administer the discounts.

Our work-around is to do this in the d/b.

Comment: OMG, and just like that, after a 3rd time of clearing cache in Civi and browser, CiviDiscount UI is now accessible ... sorry about the false alarm, but not sure why it didn't work yesterday (despite clearing cache twice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, CiviDiscount is compatible with CiviCRM 5.9.

I have a 5.9 environment with Drupal and is working as expected.

Your issue could possibly be permission related.
CiviDiscount recently introduced a permission - administer CiviDiscount

Joomla permission documentation -

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#permissions-in-joomla

Would also advise to clear CiviCRM caches –

/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/clearcache

/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1

Comment: I'm trying to configure the discounts (i.e. access CiviDiscount) using a user in the Super Admin user group so it's not permissions related; I edited my question to clarify that while the autodiscounts and applying a discount code manually work in the front end, our issue really is we cannot access the CiviDiscount GUI to administer the discounts

Comment: OMG, and just like that, after a 3rd time of clearing cache in Civi and browser, CiviDiscount UI is now accessible ... sorry about the false alarm, but not sure why it didn't work yesterday (despite clearing cache twice)

Answer (score 0):

Clearing caches brought it back for me.